# Is it true that $ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{s_i}{i + \sqrt{s_i}} = O( \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n s_i} \log n ) $?

Tags: inequality, convergence-divergence, time-series

Is the following true?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{s_i}{i + \sqrt{s_i}} = O( \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n s_i} \log n  )
$$
where $s_i \geq 1, \forall i$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $s_i=i$. Then

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{i+\sqrt{i}}\approx\int_1^n\frac{x}{x+\sqrt{x}}\,dx=1-2\sqrt{n}+n-\log 4+2\log(1+\sqrt{n})=O(n)$$
whereas the right hand side is $O(n\log n)$.